# Vinyl Siding Repair Quantities

Tags: vinyl-siding

Installed vinyl siding has missing chunks.  I would like to purchase a small quantity to replace the siding.

- What information do I need to provide to the local supply shop?
- How is siding material purchase measured?

The job needs a very small quantity.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Best bet is to take a small section to the place you plan to order from. They might be able to match it up to what they can order. Color, size, shape, etc.

Measure the areas to be repaired and convert that to square feet.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question of quantity.

Comment: @isherwood  Maybe I missed it but I didn't see in the OP a question about quantity? I see a statement but no question.

Comment: The title and question body, (including the bulleted questions) both clearly mention quantity. I'm not sure how you can miss that. There's nothing asked about matching style or color.

Comment: OP asked what information do I need to provide to the local supply shop. He asked how measured, but not how much they needed. They did not specify how much area was needing repaired. Quantity could only be determined based on square footage of repair area, which is unkown.

Answer (score 1):

Larger jobs are done by square footage, with some waste factored in (maybe 15%). You'd multiply the length and height of each rectangular area and add them up.

For small or spotty repairs, count the number of standard 12 foot lengths you'd need (by adding up short lengths if necessary). You don't really need to deal with square feet. The supplier will know how many come in a box and you can order an appropriate number of boxes.

Note that vinyl does tend to fade in the sunlight, so you may want to replace complete sections to avoid an odd appearance.

Comment: Perhaps my acquisition strategy should be to determine the type and quantities  required and "piggy back" an order onto a bigger order by working with the local vendor.

Comment: Most likely you will wait an extremely long time using this strategy. Some one would need to buy the same door, pattern,size, etc as you need. Also try a home center.